# mongoose recursively find elements in db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am writing a query to find 'n' no of videos from collection. I have set primary , secondary and tertiary language set of the user(Suppose Tamil(P), Hindi(S), English(t)). I want to first find the videos of primary language, if returns videos are less then 'n' then search from secondary language and last from tertiary language. If at any stage n videos are found then  no need to search further. I am from c background, so I am thinking to use recursion, but is there any method that I can find videos in one query.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add some pointers to let you know what actual problems you are seeing.

Comment: Multiple ways to handle it, directly via Mongodb if you want to handle it then you can use aggregation. You'll have to do a bit of reading for that but it will come handy in future. If you want to somehow get it done then use multiple find queries.

Comment: I read about aggregation, from what I understood is that aggregation works on output of the first query, But in my case I want to write a new query for (secondary or tertiary language).

Comment: you cant really do it purely recursively in Mongo, i recommend you split it into 3 queries and do your logic in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do it like this assuming the number of languages is static.

```
var langs = ['hindi', 'tamil', 'english']; //arrange the languages in the priority you want
var limit = 5;

db.videos.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group: {
                _id: null,
                vids: {
                    $push: '$$ROOT'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                vids: {
                    $concatArrays: [
                        {
                            $slice: [
                                {
                                    $filter: {
                                        input: "$vids",
                                        cond: { $eq: ["$$this.language", langs[0]] }
                                    }
                                }, limit
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            $slice: [
                                {
                                    $filter: {
                                        input: "$vids",
                                        cond: { $eq: ["$$this.language", langs[1]] }
                                    }
                                }, limit
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            $slice: [
                                {
                                    $filter: {
                                        input: "$vids",
                                        cond: { $eq: ["$$this.language", langs[2]] }
                                    }
                                }, limit
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: '$vids'
        },
        {
            $replaceWith: '$vids'
        },
        {
            $limit: limit
        }
    ])
```

make sure to add an index on the language field.

Comment: I am afraid this does not work because language priority cannot be saved in video , because is language preference is user's not video. eng might be 1st prio for user 1 and 2nd for user  2

Comment: @sonisahu i've modified the answer with a new approach. have a look...

Comment: According to my understanding, your code ==> db.videos.aggregate(
    [ { $sort: { language: 1 } .... ] cannot be used because language priority is property of user not video. so in video.aggregate it cannot be sorted. I have implemented by using 3 diff functions for now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @sonisahu actually you can remove the sort stage from the pipeline. it's just an optimization step. have a look at this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/NvGWSgTw5qH

Comment: This is complex query for me. I will understand and try it . It will take some time.Thanks.